# PHP sleep function background process

Tags: javascript, php, process, background, sleep

How can i execute PHP sleep() function as a background process with AJAX or other Javascript? Or can you tell me alternatives of this function?

Comment: background where? on the client? or server? ajax calls are already background requests on the client. and on the server you don't want to sleep(), since nothing can occur during the sleep. you'd be tying up a webserver thread/process doing absolutely nothing but snoring its head off.

Comment: okey, for example i have this code:

 $random_dice = rand(1,6);
 sleep(3);
        echo $random_dice;
And it is working like that tab is reloading for 3 seconds and after that, it shows $random dice. I want some code that will start counting 3 to 1 without tab reloading and then executes -> echo $random_dice;

Comment: `setTimeout(showrandom, 3000)`, then. implementation of `showrandom()` left as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Javascript setInterval function to periodically call your random dice function every given interval (in the example below I set this to 3 seconds. This will be much more efficient than using sleep.

```
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ randomDice() }, 3000); // 3000 ms = 3s

function randomDice() {
    //assign random number and write to some div
}
</script>
```